# Java encoding UTF-8 german Umlaute

Tags: java, parsing, encoding, utf-8

so I was trying to implement a UTF-8-encoder to parse the german Umlaute correctly for my xml-file.
I found the following code:

```
private static String convertToUTF8(String s) {
        String out = null;
        try {
            out = new String(s.getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1");
            System.out.println(out);
        } catch (java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return null;
        }
        return out;
    }
```

Receive of LDAP Attributes:

```
            LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(environment, null);
            ctx.setRequestControls(null);
            NamingEnumeration<?> namingEnum = ctx.search("...", "...",
                    getSimpleSearchControls());
            if(namingEnum.hasMore()) {
                SearchResult result = (SearchResult) namingEnum.next();
                Attributes attrs = result.getAttributes();
                namingEnum.close();
                ctx.close();
                System.out.println(attrs);
```

Example use of the Attributes:

```
String title = attrs.get("title")!=null?attrs.get("title").toString().split(":")[1].substring(1):"";
```

The "title" string is then just added to another string and sent to the server.
The Code works fine, when it has to deal with small Umlauts like "ä" or "ö" and the server also accepts these characters.
When it comes to the capital ones, like "Ä" or "Ö" it suddenly stops working and the server answers to me, that the encoding for UTF-8 is wrong.

Does anyone have an idea, how this problem can be solved?

Edit: So i found out that adding the encoding to the postRequest actually allows me to send the hardcoded UTF-8 characters to the server and it accepts it :)

Edit2: Actually I have no idea why and how, but it seems that just adding the charset to the postRequest actually fixed all my problems i had with the encoding. I will keep that in mind the next time I'm facing such a problem.

Greetings

Comment: That code is rubbish, doing these decoding/encoding steps is at best an attempt to fix already messed up `String` values and *usually* entirely unnecessary. Use a normal XML parser and if the XML file is well-formed you don't need to do any acrobatics like that. Where does the input `s` come from?

Comment: the values i have to enter are received by a ldap connection and the resulting xml file is sent over string to the server. Isn't there a simple way to just convert a given String to UTF-8 in a correct way? The s ist just a String I want to be converted, it comes as a parameter.

Comment: "convert a given String to UTF-8" doesn't mean what you mean it does. A `String` is always UTF-16 encoded in Java, by definition. Any other encodings only matter when converting byte streams (`InputStream` or simply `byte[]`) to `String` or the other way around. So at whatever point you receive data from LDAP and convert it to a `String` (likely in the library you use to access LDAP) you need to ensure it uses the correct encoding and also the same thing for when you *produce* the XML.

Comment: So why does this work for lower case Umlauts then and not for the capital ones? I am by no means any expert when it comes to Java but the result that is being printed looks pretty suitable to me. How would you approach this problem then?

Comment: It's easy to "accidentally" get something right by making similar mistakes in multiple phases. I wouldn't focus too much energy on finding out why exactly it happens works in some select cases, but more energy in finding out how to do it properly. First, try to find out which part of the process is messed up: is it getting the data from LDAP or is it producing the XML? Remove that method and replace the LDAP query with a hardcoded string like `"\u00E4\u00C4"`.

Comment: even the ones that worked start to throw errors when i put the unicode characters in like this. The server answers everytime, that it received a wrong encoding

Comment: In Java, strings have a fixed encoding. The encoding is relevant when converting bytes to string and strings to bytes. So you have to look at two places: (1) LDAP connection. Does it use the correct encoding? Is the resulting data correct? (2) XML generation: Does the XML generation use the correct encoding (in particular when output streams are involved)? Please show the relevant code.

Comment: @Development_Larry: then either you're doing something wrong when producing the XML or the server is doing something wrong when reading it. How do you produce the XML?

Comment: @JoachimSauer the XML-production is really just a string with XML-tags in it concatenated with other strings with XML-tags.

Comment: @Development_Larry: first: that's silly, use a proper XML library to produce your XML or it will be messed up. Second: that's the easy part, getting to the `String`, but how do you transfer that to the other server? That transfer step **necessarily** involves one of those `String`-to-`byte[]` conversions I mentioned above and those need to be done right.

Comment: It is transported over a postRequest and the XML-String-File is thrown into a StringRequestEntity and that is used as a RequestEntity for the postRequest; postMethod.setRequestEntity(new StringRequestEntity(xml-string));

Comment: @Development_Larry: so can you produce a [minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that involves only the step of sending the data to the server? Then we can start talking specifics. And put it in the question, this comment section is far to cramped for serious analysis.

Comment: Look at the edit

Comment: I'm not sure what you think `convertToUTF8()` does, but it does not convert to UTF-8...

Comment: @Development_Larry the constructor of [`StringRequestEntity`](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/StringRequestEntity.html) that you are using is deprecated: "*This constructor will **use the default platform charset to convert the content string** and will provide no content type.*" To ensure UTF-8 is used, use the other constructor instead: `new StringRequestEntity(xml-string, "text/xml", "utf-8")`